# Is putting too many before_filter in controller a bad thing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my code in Rails 3.1.1:

```
class ShopsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :require_user, :only => [:new, :edit, :update, :create]
  before_filter :fetch_shop, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :rate]
  before_filter :fetch_default_shop_type, :only => [:index, :new, :create]
  before_filter :fetch_default_shop_subtype, :only => [:new, :update, :edit]
  ...
end
```

I am just trying to practice a dryer approach. While in each methods in the `before_filter` doesn't do much work except passing some common variables, I don't know if this is gonna strain the controller a bit. Would it be better to reduce it, and just hardcode into individual def and not use `before_filter` on simple variable passing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Will be better to move some of filters to model.
2. It's easier to cache methods and blocks of erb then filters.